flutter local notifications works on emulator not with real device
I have tried many ways with flutter_local_notifications but couldn't find a solution to run this notifications on real device.
It works perfectly for sending simple and periodic notification but with the build apk i cant get any notification neither simple or periodic.
Tested on 2 different android devices was android 9 and android 14
app/build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

app/src/build.gradle
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.example"
    compileSdk 34
    ndkVersion "27.0.12077973"
    
    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.example"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 21
        compileSdkVersion 34
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
    implementation "androidx.core:core:1.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.media:media:1.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9"
    implementation "androidx.window:window:1.2.0"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.10.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.7.3"
}

Android Manifest
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE" />
    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
            />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <service
            android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ForegroundService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="specialUse">
            <property android:name="android.app.PROPERTY_SPECIAL_USE_FGS_SUBTYPE"
                android:value="To demonstrate how to use foreground services to show notifications" />
        </service>
        <receiver android:exported="true"
            android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ActionBroadcastReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="true"
            android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="true"
            android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

Notifications Code
class LocalNotification {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = 
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  // inititalize
  static Future init() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings 
  initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('coordinate');
    final DarwinInitializationSettings 
  initializationSettingsDarwin =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (id, title, body, payload) 
  => null,
    );
    final LinuxInitializationSettings initializationSettingsLinux =
        LinuxInitializationSettings(defaultActionName: 'Open notification');
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
            iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin,
            linux: initializationSettingsLinux);
    _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (details) => null,
    );
    await Permission.notification.request();
  }

  // Simple Notification
  static Future showSimpleNotification({
    required String title,
    required String body,
    required String payload,
  }) async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel 1',
      'simple',
      channelDescription: 'simple_notify',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      ticker: 'ticker',
      largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('enthusia'),
    );
    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .show(0, title, body, notificationDetails, payload: payload);
  }

  // Periodic Notifications
  static Future showPeriodicNotifications({
    required String title,
    required String body,
    required String payload,
  }) async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails('channel 2', 'periodic',
            channelDescription: 'periodic_notify',
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.high,
            ticker: 'ticker');
    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(
        1, title, body, RepeatInterval.everyMinute, notificationDetails,
        androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
        payload: payload);
  }
}

